# Converting smalldatetime in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

The following is not converting from i.e. July 12, 2010 to 07/12/10

```
SELECT Top 1 CONVERT(smalldatetime,[ShipDate],1) FROM [Order]
```

ShipDate is a column in [Order] of type smalldatetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you wantthe output formatted in a certain way, convert it to VARCHAR, ie:

```
SELECT Top 1 CONVERT(varchar(8),[ShipDate],1) FROM [Order]
```